# PDF Flag annotations

Tags: pdf, pdf-annotations

I try to (programmatically) write the page numbers to all pages in a PDF file.
The object I use to write looks like this:

```
493 0 obj
<</Length 96>>
stream
Q
/2 12 Tf
/DeviceRGB cs
0 0 0 scn
q
1 0 -0 1 298 32 cm
BT
1 0 0 1 -3.6 1.884 Tm
(2) Tj
ET
Q
endstream
endobj
```

It worked fine, until I tried to do it on a page which uses the flag "/rotate" :

```
23 0 obj
<</Parent 2 0 R /Rotate 180 /Contents [492 0 R 24 0 R 493 0 R ] ... >>
...
```

When tried to do so, the number I wrote came upside down (and in the top of the page instead of bottom).

I read about this in the PDF manual, and found I can use the **annotation flags**, indicating I want the written number to be fixed, and not effected by page rotation.

For that, I tried to add to the 493 obj dictionary the corresponding flag (NoRotate):

```
493 0 obj
<</Length 96 /F 16>>
stream
...
```

The only thing that actually happens is that the number I try to write doesn't show at all.

I tried to load different numbers into the "/F", but they all lead to an invisible number.

I tried to look for examples in the manual and over the net, but didn't find.

What am I doing wrong? 
Maybe I place the "/F" in the wrong location??

Comment: I guess this is the answer, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: A side remark: you set the font outside a text object. Strictly speaking that is not allowed.

Comment: @mkl, I've been told that before, I didn't find any documentation that suggests it's forbidden. It does make sense though. Unfortunately I work with a pdf package which does that (I cannot control it). Thanks.

Comment: The PDF specification pretty clearly defined which operations are allowed when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Adobe's PDF Reference v1.7 ([link to PDF](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf)), **8.4.2 Annotation Flags**, the flag `/F` only applies to *annotations* -- objects with a `/Type` of `/Annot`, and appearing in a PDF as sticky notes, text edits, and clickable rectangles.

It seems you have to provide the rotation yourself, using the `Tm` operator.